# i need to use a post request on my vue js code but i just have with curl and i dont know how to write it axios

Tags: vue.js, curl, post, axios

i need to use a post request on my vue js code but i just have with curl and i dont know how to write it axios :
curl -X POST -F "reference_format=bibtex" -F "file=@path/to/file.pdf;type=application/pdf" /api/references/download

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc of axios (https://github.com/axios/axios) you should have something like that:

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const form = new FormData();
form.append('reference_format', 'bibtex');
form.append('file', 'path/to/file.pdf');
axios.post('yoursite.com/api/references/download', form);
```